# How can I call the R-programming packages in my Mathematica?

Tags: functions, programming, function-construction, packages, functional-style

I am trying to call the R-programming package called `highfrequency` in my Mathematica so that I can use its function `rCov`. I tried to call this by using

```
Needs["RLink`"];
InstallR[];
install.packages;
REvaluate["library(highfrequency)"]
```

Then, I receive the following error:

```
REvaluate::rerr: Failed to retrieve the value for variable or piece of code 
library(highfrequency). The following R error was encountered: Error in library    
(highfrequency) : 
there is no package called 'highfrequency' >>
```

This error is the same no matter what different R-packages I call within Mathematica.
However, I think the Mathematica command `REvaluate` may not be appropriate in calling R-packages.
May I know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what realized covariance means. Perhaps the easiest solution is to use RLink and directly use the R implementation. Otherwise, please edit the question with enough information so that we can construct such a function -- perhaps with an example showing what calculation you desire to implement.

Comment: @bill s: Thanks a lot. Then may I know how I can use RLink and directly use the R implementation? I have never tried in that way before.

Comment: You need to install R the package first using [`install.packages`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/install.packages).  With RLink this is only possible on Windows.  Otherwise you can install the package into an external R installation (separate from RLink), then [set up RLink to use this external R](http://www.nd.edu/~szhorvat/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html)

Comment: It looks like this package was removed from CRAN though ... http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highfrequency/index.html

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks. That sounds strange since I still can use that package just right now in my R-programming as well. My error message is the same even though I change to different R-packages. Besides, I amended my question but still the implementation of your suggestion was not so easy yet. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What do you mean precisely when you say that you "still can use that package just right now"? Do you mean that you can use it when you start R separately from Mathematica?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, I can use it when I use it in R separately from Mathematica.

Comment: I think it's a matter of getting the correct Mathematica coding syntax when calling R-packages into Mathematica.

Comment: @Eric That means that you have already installed this package, possibly before it was removed from CRAN.  (It's still possible to install it now, but it's not as simple as `install.packages('highfrequency')`.)  Now the important point to realize is that RLink comes with a built-in installation of R which is completely separate from that one that you installed yourself.  It doesn't contain the same packages.

Comment: The workaround: set up RLink to use the external R installation that you normally use on your computer, [based on my guide](http://www.nd.edu/~szhorvat/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html).  If you find the guide difficult to follow, let me know and I'll improve it.  This is not about syntax: you used the correct syntax for your command.  You just have to ask RLink to use the installation of R which contains this package.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your comment. I am looking more into details now. However, since I am interested in installing R-packages into Mathematica not the R-programming itself yet since the code above seems to call the R-program, I am not sure how I can find this need in the document you provided yet..I'll try more but if you ever happen to know the straightforward way to call the R-package in Mathematica, I would appreciate if I could know. Thank you very much, though.

Comment: @Eric I think you may have misunderstood how RLink works. It simply connects an R installation to Mathematica and allows you to execute R code (using that R installation) from within Mathematica, then retrieve the results.  It is not possible to "install R packages into Mathematica".  You need to: 1. install the package into an R installation (already done) 2. connect Mathematica to that R installation 3. load the package using `REvaluate["library(somepackage)"]` 4. use the package functions.  Also, do not confuse loading a package (`library`) and installing it (`install.packages`).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks. Then, looking at your steps, I think the problem comes from step 2 where I have to connect Mathematica and R installation. From your provided document, it seems like the command `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.3"]` is supposed to give a solution to this step. However, if so, I would appreciate if I could know what the `RHomeLocation` should be in this code, if possible.

Comment: Besides, my R-programming is version 3.1.1 where your document suggests me not to have upper version than 2.15.3 or so since I am using Windows 8..But it's strange that it says it "does" support higher version of R-program if I have Mathematica 10.0.1. which I do have now but it still does not work even though I fix this into `C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.1`

Comment: @Eric can you join [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Hi again. I opened my mathematica again and did the exactly the same thing you described but I still got the same error that I had before..May I ask what you think think the cause is? If you need me to join the chat again, I'll do so.

Comment: @Eric Have you checked which version of R you are connected to?  `REvaluate["R.version.string"]`.  If it's not 3.1.1, then `UninstallR[]`, then `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> ...]` again.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, you are right. When I check my R-version, it says {"R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)"}. But even after I uninstall it and do the InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> ...]  again, it still has the same error and the version does not seem to change. I used the "RHomeLocation" to be the R-file path that I used for my project and I wonder whether this is right.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Ah..now it works. The InstallR[] was not supposed to be mixed with my command. After I removed it, it gave me the correct version. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know what realized covariance means. Perhaps the easiest solution is to use RLink and directly use the R implementation. Here are some links to the documentation to get you started.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html

Comment: Thanks. But if I have a certain R-command like `rCov` only unique to the R-package called `highfrequency` but not a general R-command, do you know how possibly I can bring either the `highfrequency` package and/or the `rCov` command unique only to the `highfrequecy` package?

Comment: I amended my whole question. Please check.