# Why isn't Mathematica acknowledging my R function?

Tags: rlink

I believe my problem is similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64572/how-can-i-call-the-r-programming-packages-in-my-mathematica) but I couldn't solve it. After installing the package *readstata13*, I run the following code in R and it works fine:

`data <- read.dta13("D:/Monash/ETC5860 - Research paper/data/Data_Release/conditionfactors_stress_d06302013.dta")`

Then I try to do it from Mathematica but it doesn't work:

```
Needs["RLink`"];
InstallR[];
REvaluate["install.packages('readstata13')"]
Shallow[testdata = 
REvaluate[
"read.dta13('***samepath***/conditionfactors_stress_d06302013.dta')"]]
```

I get the following:

```
    Error:could not find function "read.dta13"
```

Can someone help me fix this? The owner of the aforementioned question said something about not mixing Install[]R with his command but I don't know what that means.

Thanks in advance,

Thad

Comment: @Szabolcs, I followed your instructions under [Setting up RLink](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html) but I get the following error message when I type `InstallR["RHomeLocation" ->"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.1"]`: _Error: R.DLL version does not match (DLL:3.4.1, expecting:3.3.0)_

Comment: I'm sorry, I won't be able to look into that until the weekend (Windows is not my default platform).

Comment: I forgot to `REvaluate["library(readstata13)"]` in my _Mathematica_ code before `REvaluate["read.dta13(...)"]`. But Mathematica still doesn't acknowledge the package _readstata13_. Is there a step that I'm missing after installing a package? Maybe I need to reference the package before using it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I ran `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.1"]` after running `InstallR[]`. That's why I got the error message. It works fine now. {;^)